# EF5: Multiple result sets from stored procedure

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I followed [this](http://milesquaretech.com/Blog/post/2012/03/19/Entity-Framework-5-%E2%80%93-Multiple-Entity-Typed-Result-Sets-from-a-Stored-Procedure.aspx) article to retrieve multiple entity sets from a stored procedure.

I have altered the column mappings of my entities so they pass through Resharper.
Do I have to rewrite the column mappings in the result mapping?

For example I have the following EntitySetMapping:

```
      <EntitySetMapping Name="IrmaObjectConfiguraties">
        <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="IrmaModel.IrmaObjectConfiguratie">
          <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="IrmaObjectConfiguratie">
            <ScalarProperty Name="Gid" ColumnName="GID" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="IrmaObjectGid" ColumnName="IrmaObject_GID" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="IrmaConfiguratieGid" ColumnName="IrmaConfiguratie_GID" />
          </MappingFragment>
        </EntityTypeMapping>
      </EntitySetMapping>
```

This entity is returned bij as part of the stored proc result sets:

```
        <ResultMapping>
          <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="IrmaModel.IrmaObjectConfiguratie">
            <!--ScalarProperty Name="Gid" ColumnName="Gid" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="IrmaObjectGid" ColumnName="IrmaObject_Gid" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="IrmaConfiguratieGid" ColumnName="IrmaConfiguratie_Gid" /-->
          </EntityTypeMapping>
        </ResultMapping>
```

When I remove the remarks the execution of the imported function goes ok, but when there is no column mapping I retrieve the following error:

> *The data reader is incompatible with the specified
>   'IrmaModel.IrmaObjectConfiguratie'. A member of the type,
>   'IrmaObjectGid', does not have a corresponding column in the data
>   reader with the same name.*

As a workaround I could define all column mappings again, but is is also possible to use the column mappings that are defined in the `EntitySetMapping`?

Comment: Why not get rid of resharper or at least its arbritrary rules instead?

Comment: I like CamelCase above the use of underscores. unfortunately contains the database underscores in the column names.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think ResultMapping re-uses mappings from EntitySet mappings. Seems (I am not 100% positive here) that if you don't specify property <-> column mappings EF will try to use property names as column names in the resultset returned by your stored procedure.

Comment: As long as the column names returned by the stored procedure match the entities property names you don't need to add the mappings. But if the mappings are the same as in the entity mapping definition, you need to add the same mappings by the result set mappings. It would be nice if you could reuse the entity mappings by specifying an extra attribute like PropertyMapping=EntityMapping

Comment: I don't think it's possible at the moment.